# Which TLS protocol will Windows Server choose?

Tags: windows, security, ssl

We have one Application Server and one Database Server. The client connects the application from his workstation. On vulnerability report of Application and Database server. TLS 1.0 is found vulnerable.

So we decided to upgrade it from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2.
As by default, there is no TLS 1.0 entry exist in 2012 and 2016 so we put the entry in REGISTRY and make it DISABLEBYDEFAULT (0) and ENABLED (1) for both Client and Server entry.

1) my 1st request is if there is no entry of TLS then please confirm OS consider TLS 1.0 as enabled by default or not. 
2) my 2nd request is if we enable all the protocols on Application Server and Database Server e.g as below.

```
TLS 1.0
Client = Enable
Server = Enable

TLS 1.1
Client = Enable
Server = Enable

TLS 1.2
Client = Enable
Server = Enable
```

Someone know in the above case if the client connect to the application, which TLS protocol would be used.

Comment: This needs more context. However, the usual configuration is to try the best (TLS1.2 in this case) first and only go down if both can't agree on that.

Comment: We have one Application Server and one Database Server. The client connects the application from his workstation. On vulnerability report of Application and Database server. TLS 1.0 is found vulnerable.
So we decided to upgrade it from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2.
As by default, there is no TLS 1.0 entry exist in 2012 and 2016 so we put the entry in REGISTRY and make it DISABLEBYDEFAULT (0) and ENABLED (1) for both Client and Server entry. 
if there is no entry of TLS then please confirm OS consider TLS 1.0 as enabled by default or not.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Depends on the TLS version sent by the client. If the client sends a 1.0 version, that is what will be used.

Comment: its mean if we have all three (1.0, 1.1 and 1.2) enabled it will first search 1.0 and stopped. and will not go further to search for the rest of the TLSs (1.1 and 1.2).
if we disable TLS 1.0 and enable 1.1 and 1.2, it will search for 1.0 found disable now go for 1.1 and 1.2 in this case it will choose latest one. which will be TLS 1.2 .Please correct me if my understanding is correct.